# Rhythmbox is crashing on start

Tags: rhythmbox

I'm using ubuntu 10.10 and until about 3 days ago rhythmbox worked fine but now when I start it, it opens, then after 4 second it crashes.
When running it from terminal I get this:

```
>    ~$ rhythmbox  
(rhythmbox:27420): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
** Message: pygobject_register_sinkfunc is deprecated (GstObject)

>    (rhythmbox:27420): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed  
    Segmentation fault
```

and then rhythmbox closes.
What to do?

**Edit:**
Disabled most of the plugins and it's not crashing now, but i still get this when running from terminal:

```
>(rhythmbox:27420): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed ** Message: pygobject_register_sinkfunc is deprecated (GstObject)

>(rhythmbox:27420): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: g_object_unref: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
```

Should I worry?

Comment: I'm having the same issue but noticed that if the device that my music is stored on is not mounted, Rhythmbox launches normally. Once I mount my music, it's detected then listed in my library and I can use Rhythmbox again. My best guess is that my library got to a certain size that cannot be handled at launch-time. To test this, you could hide/move everything that is in your library then slowly re-introduce it to see at what point this error occurs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Still no solutions except to remove ubuntu one music store plugin.

Even connecting to ubuntu one then laucnhing rhythmbox solved nothing.

Then i tried to purge all local rhythmbox data so it would start fresh still crashes on launch

1. Remove ubuntu one music store plugin from synaptic
2. Delete/clear all local rhythmbox references with

   > rm ~/.local/share/rhythmbox/ ~/.cache/rhythmbox/
   >   ~/.gconf/apps/rhythmbox/ -r
3. Launch Rhythmbox and disable all music store/fm rhythmbox plugins,
   then quit rhythmbox
4. Reinstall ubuntuone music store plugin
5. Launch Rhythmbox again and now it shouldnt crash, renable all the
   plugins you disabled

or you can try this also 
Try disabling or uninstalling.

To disable run this in terminal

```
gconf-editor
```

navigate to apps - rhythmbox - plugins - umusicstore and disable (uncheck
[image]

Or search rhythmbox in *synaptic* and remove the plugin (rhythmbox-ubuntuone-music-store)

Comment: I already removed the ubuntuone plugin with sudo apt-get remove rhythmbox-ubuntuone-music-store and it changed nothing.

Comment: @Kristal did you follow all the steps which i told u

Comment: I disabled most of the plugins (radio stations and more) and now it works fine, not crashing. But I still get those errors when opening it from terminal just without the 'Segmentation fault'

Comment: @Kristal Now also u are facing any error

Comment: It's working fine now.

Comment: @Kristal Sound good

Comment: Please don't just tell people to remove some thing which you think might be a problem for "questions" like this. Please inform that they should file bug reports instead, and/or upgrade from no longer supported versions if they're running one.

Comment: @dobey  agreed. downvoted :(. i just want 2 help him in running that .

Comment: @Gaurav_Java be careful with what you copy from the forums and how you present that data.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would recommend, is to upgrade to Ubuntu 11.04 at least. Ubuntu 10.10 will reach End Of Life in a few weeks, when 12.04 is released (which I'd really recommend upgrading to).

The crash likely had nothing to do with Ubuntu One, but it's impossible to know that as you asked a question here, instead of reporting the bug. If things crash, please report bugs, rather than asking questions on askUbuntu (which is not a bug reporting forum).

Answer (score 0):

Well in my case I have music stored on a network share. I deleted some files from the library on another computer. When i started up Rhythmbox it still showed these songs for a couple of seconds and then vanishes. And so does Rhythmbox.

So I deleted `~/.local/share/rhythmbox` and it started up without a hitch. It just needed to re-index the location where the music is stored.

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely someone reads that post because of Lucid's oldness but not impossible (e.g. I'm constrained to use it at work) so here we are.

A little bit of context:

In my case (Ubuntu Lucid Lynx aka 10.04LTS) Rhythmbox 0.13.1 --meanwhile worked flawlessly with local(hard disk) music files in my playlists-- after a point in time(only ultimately really) crashed every time I tried to use *Radio Browser* and after a while I pressed *Radiostation List* button precisely in loading Icecast stations phase(right after downloading) and furthermore hanged(CPU at 100%) almost every time I clicked on a bookmarked radio station so I had to kill the application and restarting it with the same results every time.

Starting the application from shell bring that output:

```
$ rhythmbox

(rhythmbox:3604): Rhythmbox-WARNING **: Could not open device /dev/radio0
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/rpdb2.py:308: DeprecationWarning: the sets module is deprecated
  import sets
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/rpdb2.py:313: DeprecationWarning: The popen2 module is deprecated.  Use the subprocess module.
  import popen2

(rhythmbox:3604): Gtk-WARNING **: gtk_widget_size_allocate(): attempt to allocate widget with width -5 and height 0

(rhythmbox:3604): librsvg-WARNING **: CSS parsing error


(rhythmbox:3604): librsvg-WARNING **: CSS parsing error


(rhythmbox:3604): librsvg-WARNING **: CSS parsing error

Segmentation fault
```

The lines

```
$ rhythmbox

(rhythmbox:3604): Rhythmbox-WARNING **: Could not open device /dev/radio0
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/rpdb2.py:308: DeprecationWarning: the sets module is deprecated
  import sets
/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/rpdb2.py:313: DeprecationWarning: The popen2 module is deprecated.  Use the subprocess module.
  import popen2
```

are outputted every time I start Rhythmbox so are unrelated to that problem

the line

```
(rhythmbox:3604): Gtk-WARNING **: gtk_widget_size_allocate(): attempt to allocate widget with width -5 and height 0
```

is output  when I choose the *Radio Browser* (under *Radio* item) from the left menu widget or *Radiostation List* button I don't remember well

instead of the lines

(rhythmbox:3604): librsvg-WARNING **: CSS parsing error

```
(rhythmbox:3604): librsvg-WARNING **: CSS parsing error


(rhythmbox:3604): librsvg-WARNING **: CSS parsing error

Segmentation fault
```

are in output in loading Icecast stations phase(right after downloading) and consequently when crashed

What I did to solve the problem was simply rename two Rhythmbox's related directories (obviously after have closed the application) and then restart the application(that regenerate those directories). What I lost are the playlists (made of local music files) but that's easy to recreate
The renamed directories are

```
~/.local/share/rhythmbox/ ---> ~/.local/share/rhythmbox.old/
```

and

```
~/.cache/rhythmbox/ ---> ~/.cache/rhythmbox.old/
```

Notice as I said earlier  in either case Rhythmbox regenerates them and much importantly don't crash as did before

Comment: @Yufenyuy Veyeh Dider Thanks for your corrections :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was having another error message. But, deleting local cache and config files was the solution.

```bsh
rm ~/.local/share/rhythmbox/ ~/.cache/rhythmbox/ -r
```

Command `rm` stands for **remove**.
The argument `-r` is for deleting recursively.

---

OS: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (64 bits)