# Rhythmbox starts muted at launch. Changing volume has no effect on playback

Tags: sound, 16.04, rhythmbox, amarok

Rhythmbox has recently started malfunctioning on my ubuntu 16.04. It always starts muted and changing the volume(system volume or the volume control from rhythmbox) has no effect whatsoever. I am sure it is problem with rhythmbox because all other sounds(system sounds, video playback, games) are working just fine. No problem with Gnome Music either.Same problem has been encountered with Amarok on my system, though. I tried --pruge remove rhythmbox and then also installing it using --install-suggests but no use. Any help would be highly appreciated because Rhythmbox is my favorite media player(in spite of having gnome music, dragon player, vlc, and amarok).

Comment: it's just suggestion , try to install another music player such as Clementine or check this link may help you with rhythmbox
http://askubuntu.com/questions/117865/rhythmbox-is-crashing-on-start?rq=1

Comment: In my case the issue is slightly different... Rhythmbox always starts muted (doesn't remember volume set before closing) but it works normally - with exception that I have to increase volume after each launch. I wonder if it's related somehow.

Answer (score 0):

This answer helps ONLY IF YOU HAVE CINNAMON INSTALLED!
Login to your Cinnamon DE and do the following

Right click on the panel and select "Add applets to the panel".

In the window that opens click on the "Available applets(Online)" tab.

From the listed applets install "Sound-with-apps-volume" applet.

Start Rhythmbox and play any track. Open the sound-with-apps-volume menu and unmute Rhythmbox.

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer (actually a workaround) for **mbdevpl**. I have exactly the same with Debian 9 (Stretch) and Mate 1.16.2.
My workaround is to add a launcher for Rhythmbox, on the top panel, containing the command
`rhythmbox-client --set-volume 100`
Since I want Rhythmbox to start at login, I used the same command in an instance of the Startup applications pane.
Hope this gives at list some relief  ^__^

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you have VLC installed and it is set to mute? If I muted VLC, and then start Rhythmbox, it will not make any sound despite Rhythmbox being unmuted.

My fix is to close all Rhythmbox instances, then open VLC, unmute VLC, close VLC and start Rhythmbox again.

Why? I don't know. Sure sounds like a bug.